# Does main() need to be in every script containing handlers?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httphandler

Experienced Java programmer trying to learn Python.  I have an applicaiton on Google App Engine and want to move my admin Handlers to a separate file.  So now I have main.py and admin.py.  I've set up app.yaml to route traffic properly, and have added the call to WSGIApplication() in each file to route to the appropriate Handler.

My question is does each script file need def main() and the corresponding if statement:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/admin/(.*)', Admin)],
                                       debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from listing the same script file twice in app.yaml for different permission levels based on path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this in any script that's referenced directly your `app.yaml`.

Any time App Engine needs to send a request to one of your scripts, it goes through the following steps:

1. Has the script been imported before? If not, just import it and stop.
2. If the script has been imported before, does it have a function called `main`? If not, import it again and stop.
3. Execute the `main` function of the script.

The reason it does this is because importing modules is relatively expensive, and there's no point re-importing them for every single request. So, it provides an optimisation: if you provide a function called `main`, on requests after the first one it will simply execute this function instead of reimporting the script. The `if __name__ == "__main__":` stanza is there to detect the first import of the script, and execute `main` manually for that first request.

In a nutshell, the answer is that you can leave both `main` and the `if` clause out, or include them both. If you leave them out, your app will be slightly less efficient, but you'll only run into trouble if you include one of the two but not the other.

Comment: My question was specific to scripts implementing RequestHandlers.  But you're saying that *any* script that is loaded should include this idiom in order to make imports more efficient - correct?

Comment: @Will Any script that is referenced from `app.yaml`. You don't need to put it in scripts that contain RequestHandlers but aren't executed directly, or any other scripts other than those listed directly in `app.yaml`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary: you could just have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

I seem to remember reading that Google recommend a `main()` function because they cache it in byte-compiled form, rather than recompiling the file each time a request comes in. Although it probably doesn't make much difference for an admin thing.

Comment: To rephrase slightly, a `main()` method is not required, but a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block *is* required.

Comment: @Luke: That depends on Google's setup. The `if __name__` trick checks whether you're importing it or running it, and I don't know precisely what Google do. But I'd definitely recommend having it in place.

Comment: Good point. I'm a Python newb. Here's what Nick Johnson wrote about it on his blog: "instead of re-executing your Python executable for each request, a single Python runtime is used for multiple requests. Each request simply re-imports the main handler script for your app, which results in re-executing all the code in it, though modules loaded from it are not re-imported. As a further optimisation, if you provide a function called 'main' in your handler module, that function is executed on the second and subsequent requests, instead of re-importing the module."